# jquery Slider not working on firefox however it is working on chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery sliders on the page link mention below, but the sliders does'not works on firfox..however it is working fine on chrome & in IE.

I found the below mentioned error on firefox,

> ### PreloadCSSimages.js  Line 88
>
> SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
> [Break On This Error]
>
> if(sheets[sheetIndex].cssRules || sheets[sheetIndex].rules){

**here is the code on line number 88, for which firefox shows error:**

> if(sheets[sheetIndex].cssRules || sheets[sheetIndex].rules){

***Link:*** http://www.virtualmob.co.uk/products/test_landing_pages/PAM/

Comment: also on the footer twitter doesnot come up too in firefox..

Comment: which `firefox` version do you have, it works fine on `15.0.1`

Comment: @bborisovs Sir, firfox 16.0.2
but slider & twitter feeds also works cool in ie too..it only does'not works on firefox

Comment: @bborisovs, do you have any idea why it is'not working on Firefox 16.0.2, it also shows the error which i mentioned above in line 88..let me edit my question & let me place the code on line number 88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove the general.js which is conflicting..now it works fine on firefox too